# Use twitter-bootstrap custom select menu in ui-bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I use the ui-bootstrap with angularjs framework, but there is nothing to replace the select menu in the html. I found [this plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), which work very well, but it is a twitter-bootstrap plugin. How could I use this plugin with the angular-ui-bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a directive written for the bootstrap-select library located [here](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select). Angular supports the native html select element and is documented [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)